# How to create Linked Service for Salesforce in Azure Synapse using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

As per the requirements, I am working with Azure Synapse Environment using Python. I need to create a Linked Service for Salesforce to be utilized in pipeline later.
But I'm facing an error and couldn't get better documentations from Microsoft.

Simplified code -

```
from azure.synapse.artifacts import ArtifactsClient
from azure.synapse.artifacts.models import *


sf_ls_name = "testnotebookls"
sf_env_url = "https://login.salesforce.com"  
sf_user = "<username>"             
sf_pass = '<password>',
sf_security_token = '<security-token>', 
    
properties=SalesforceLinkedService(environment_url=sf_env_url,
                                           password=sf_pass,
                                           username=sf_user,
                                           security_token=sf_security_token)

client.linked_service.begin_create_or_update_linked_service(linked_service_name=sf_ls_name, properties=properties)
```

Please note down that I've created **client** object and able to get linked services and perform synapse related operations.

**Error**

```
DeserializationError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\Someuser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\folder\folder\salesforce\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\synapse\artifacts\_serialization.py:710, in Serializer.body(self, data, data_type, **kwargs)
    705         deserializer.key_extractors = [
    706             rest_key_case_insensitive_extractor,
    707             attribute_key_case_insensitive_extractor,
    708             last_rest_key_case_insensitive_extractor,
...
   1257         found_key = key
   1258         break
-> 1260 return data.get(found_key)

SerializationError: (', DeserializationError: (", AttributeError: \'tuple\' object has no attribute \'get\'", \'Unable to deserialize to object: type\', AttributeError("\'tuple\' object has no attribute \'get\'"))', 'Unable to build a model: (", AttributeError: \'tuple\' object has no attribute \'get\'", \'Unable to deserialize to object: type\', AttributeError("\'tuple\' object has no attribute \'get\'"))', DeserializationError(", AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'", 'Unable to deserialize to object: type', AttributeError("'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'")))
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve it, it was because the security_token and password should be a type of SecretBase Class (Which can't be used directly, use child class SecureString)

**Example**

```
sf_ls_name = "testnotebookls"
sf_env_url = "https://login.salesforce.com"  
sf_user = "username"
sf_pass = SecureString(value='<password>')
sf_security_token = SecureString(value='<security-token>')
```